# How to turn off "periodically_call_remote"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have `periodically_call_remote` updating a div (`main_div`) in my web app. This `main_div` contains links that the user can click that invokes an action that overwrites data within `main_div`.

My problem is that the timer is running on the `periodically_call_remote` function and even though the user has navigated away from the page, that function call still wants to return. If the `main_div` is present on the page the function call wipes out the data that was currently being displayed. If the `main_div` is not on the page then the javascript returns an error dialog.

So, my question is, when the user navigates away from the div that is periodically being updated, how do I stop the function call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This thread: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/119372 provided the answer that I needed.

Essentially it boils down to overriding `periodically_call_remote` in the `application_helper.rb` file to put the `PeriodicalExecutor` into a js variable.

Then, you can call `poller.stop();` whenever you want to cancel the calls.

Answer (score -2):

You would want to setup the layout/template to conditionally enable the updater